# "bundle install" fail while install rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bundler

I am trying to install rspec-rails on Ubuntu but I am encountering some problems.

Here are my exact steps:

1) Changed my Gemfile to:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0.beta4'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta.17'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.0.0.beta.17'
end
```

2) Type "bundle install" and I get the following error:

> /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /home/steve/.gem/specs (Errno::EACCES)

3) If I continue with my installation instructions and type "rails generate rspec:install"
I get the following error (but it might have been caused by #2 failing)

> Could not find gem 'rspec (= 2.0.0.beta.17, runtime)' in the gems available on this machine.

I was unable to find a solution for this on Google.  This is the [link](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#fnref:3.1) to the tutorial I am trying to follow.  My dev enviroment is Ubuntu 10.04, Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 3.0.0 beta 4.

Thanks.

Comment: How about `sudo bundle install`, but not a good idea.

Comment: What output do you get if you type `ls -l /home/steve/.gem/`?

Answer (score 8):

You probably have a permission misconfiguration in your .gem folder.
You can reset the permissions using

```
$ sudo chown -R steve:steve ~/.gem
```

or you can easily remove the folder and let bundler/rubygems recreate it.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed the same issue for me.. My .gem directory was owned by root.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you have rspec being included in the development config too?

I can't test here - but I reckon if you include:

```
gem 'rspec', '2.0.0.beta.17'
```

...in your group :development do...end block, that might fix the issue. It would seem logical to me as I think rspec-rails needs the rspec functionality itself in order to be able to generate the necessary files. You're probably safer as well if you make the blocks like this:

```
group :development do
  gem 'rspec', '2.0.0.beta.17'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta.17'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.0.0.beta.17'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.0.beta.17'
end
```

...as that way the necessary files should be getting included in both environments. I don't know for sure, I just hope this hasn't confused matters further (I'm a total Rails newbie!)

Comment: I agree, I'm pretty sure they need to be together.

Answer (score 1):

If changing ownership of your ~/.gem folder doesn't work try checking the ownership of the folder you are currently in. To check your folder permissions type:

`$ ls -la`

If you see anything that says "root root" it needs to be changed to your current user account.

`$ sudo chown -R steve:steve /path/to/folder`

Answer (score 1):

just remove `.bundle` directory in your application path